# Will Multithreading and Multiprocessing work with or without this:

Tags: multithreading, python-multithreading

Will Multithreading and Multiprocessing work with or without this,
`if __name__=="__main__"` ??

Answer (score 0):

`__name__` is a global variable that is automatically initialized to refer to a string—either the name of the [*module*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) in which `__name__` appears or, the special value, `"__main__"`, if it appears in a script or top-level program.

This pattern is used in many Python source files:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # test or demo the module
    ...
```

The test/demo code is run if you run the source file as a script, or it doesn't get run if the source file is `import`ed as a module.

Importing [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) doesn't change what `if __name__ == "__main__"` does, and `if __name__ == "__main__"` doesn't change what `multiprocessing` or `threading` do. Those modules are no different in that respect from any other Python module (e.g., [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html), or [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html), or [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html))